# SQl performance -Indexing

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, non-clustered-index

Here I am having a table called Tuser  with greater than 100K records as I need to get  those records directly with a conditiion

here is my query

```
SELECT TU.USERID,TU.ORGUNITID,TU.LOGINNAME,TU.LOGINPASSWORD,TU.FIRSTNAME,TU.LASTNAME,      
  TU.HINTQUESTION,TU.HINTANSWER,TU.CONTACTID,TU.STATUSTYPE FROM TUSER(NOLOCK) TU       
  INNER JOIN TUSERORGUNIT(NOLOCK) TUO ON TUO.USERID = TU.USERID      
  WHERE TU.ORGUNITID = @ORGUNITID
```

it is taking 4 to 5 sec when there are lessa than 3k records

now its taking on an average 35sec to execute.

This is my Execution plan

[image]

Do I need to create any index? and why? can u explain?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Which DB? have you checked explain plan? It will show which part of query is taking time.

Comment: SQl Server 2008 R2.. i checked execution plan ..

Comment: can u add create scripts on those two tables?